# ASIO Driver in VMware / Routing Audio From Guest To Host

Tags: drivers, audio, virtual-machine, vmware, asio

I'm attempting to use ASIO in Cubase 6 with a VMware Virtual Machine running Windows 7 64bit. After installing ASIO4ALL in the virtual machine, I loaded up Cubase and tried selecting ASIO4ALL as my sound driver, except when I do VMware gives me an error saying that "Error in creating sound stream, audio may not work". And well, it doesn't work. I can see audio being played in Cubase but nothing coming out of my speakers. If I close Cubase for example and go on anything like Youtube however, audio works again.

Has anyone come across this before? Any help is appreciated!